# how to design software using the patterns for mobile apps

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mobile, architecture, software-design

I need to develop an mobile app in Android which will be used by few office people only and below are the requirements :

- Generally in office work-space or meeting rooms we have WAP to access internet,which is connected to Router and then to Internet server.
- Now the app should be able to communicate to WAP, Router to get their status.
- app should be for mobile devices.
- only registered users can use this app
- only single app on each mobile
- 1st install the app and register with respective company before using it.
- as of now app is for Android platform but in future may need same app for iOS mobiles.

I need suggestion/guidance on how design the app using before starting the code. 
As of now i can think of using 2 design patterns i.e. Singleton and Factory Pattern (for User registration). Also i'm not sure in which language should i develop communication library so that it can be used cross-platform also.

Do we need to follow any client-server architecture  for above app ?

Please throw some light on above.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe I can recommend some online  tutorials which will help search Derek Banas he has a lot on that. He talks about everything in more than 10 videos.

Comment: @Syombua -please give me link

Comment: Hey sorry about that am using my phone. I figured if I share theWebsite you will peruse through it. Everything is there what you want tutorials plus codes. Take your time .

Comment: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/factory-design-pattern-tutorial/ just go through the website. Very resourceful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about **iOS Design Patterns**:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns